# MongoDB Rolling calculations

Tags: mongodb

So I haven't used MongoDB in a long time, was wondering if there are any built in ways (or plugins) to help keep tracking of various calculations without having to do the work manually.

For example...

```
Product schema
<id>
<product name>
```

```
Reviews schema
<id>
<product_id>
<score>
```

If I want to keep track of the average score so I can query/sort very quickly (without having to calculate it every query) I was planning to add to the Product schema something like

```
<reviews.score.sum>
<reviews.score.median>
<reviews.score.count>
```

That would save the DB a lot of work obviously when trying to query products where the average review > X. Or finding the top X products by most reviews.
But then I would have to do the math / calculations work on every change. Is there any built in ways to have MongoDB auto calculate some of these common math operations on document change? Or do I need to do it manually/look into some other time series/analytical DB?

Comment: if its low writes, you can use [`change streams`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/changeStreams/) and update those values in every update.If too many writes are happening you can calculate them every some period of time with some data staleness

Comment: Nothing out of the box in v5- all stats are specific to your application and interpretation of stored documents. You can do it  on application level - see oreilly.com/library/view/mongodb-applied-design/9781449340056/ch04.html#pre-aggregated-reports for inspiration.  Basically you have pre-aggregation, bucketing, materialized views.